# Flex 4: Add Items to a dropdownlist progmatically

Tags: drop-down-menu, flex4

I would like to add items to a dropdownlist progmatically.

I have an empty drop downlist and depending on a number of factors I then populate it with various action choices.

the Drop Down list is called dlFirstChoice and I would like to add some values to it, can some one give me the basic code to do so, I have tired ILists and Arrays as the Dataprovider but clearly Im doing something wrong.

Please and thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var dropListDb:ArrayList=new ArrayList();
     dropListDb.addItem({label: "Equals (List)"});
     dropListDb.addItem({label: "Is Between"});
     dlFirstChoice.visible = true;
     dlFirstChoice.dataProvider=dropListDb;
     dlFirstChoice.selectedIndex=0;
```